# CakePHP 3 - Can't save a foreign key

Tags: php, model, cakephp-3.0

So, I have a table called *posts* and another called *users*.

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `users_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

These are the respective models *Posts* and *Users*.

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('posts');
        $this->displayField('title');
        //$this->primaryKey(['id', 'users_id']);
        $this->primaryKey(['id']);

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'users_id'
        ]);
    }

public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('users');
        $this->displayField('name');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->hasMany('Posts', [
            'foreignKey' => 'id'
        ]);
    }
```

The problem is that when I enter a new post, the value of users_id comes as 0, even though in debug mode it appears as 1. This is the debug:

```
{

    'users' => [
        'users_id' => '1'
    ],
    'title' => 'Teste title',
    'description' => 'Test desc',
    'status' => (int) 1,
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        'users' => true,
        'title' => true,
        'description' => true,
        'status' => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Posts'

}
{ "users": { "users_id": "1" }, "title": "Teste title", "description": "Test desc", "status": 1 }
```

These are respectively the controller and the view:

```
public function add()
    {
        $post = $this->Posts->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $post = $this->Posts->patchEntity($post, $this->request->data, ['associated' => ['Users']]);
            if ($this->Posts->save($post)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The post has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The post could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $users = $this->Posts->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
        $this->set(compact('post', 'users'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['post']);
    }

echo $this->Form->create($post);
echo $this->Form->input('users.users_id', array('default' => 1));
echo $this->Form->input('title');
echo $this->Form->input('description', ['rows' => '3']);
echo $this->Form->input('status', array('type'=>'select', 'options'=>array(1 => 'Enabled',2 => 'Disabled'), 'default'=>'1'));
echo $this->Form->button(__('Save Post'));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

I do not know what may be causing the error, the code seems the same as others I checked and that work.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the form, you should use:

```
$this->Form->input('users.id', array('default' => 1));
```

instead of

```
$this->Form->input('users.users_id', array('default' => 1));
```

Also don't forget to associate the Users table whenyou are saving the data:

```
$posts = TableRegistry::get('Articles');
$post = $posts->newEntity($data, [
    'associated' => ['Users']
]);
$posts->save($post);
```

Reference:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-belongsto-associations

### Edit

The method I suggested works great with a different type of entity like Categories, if you have to work with Users is easier and safer the suggestion of @Manohar Khadka

Answer (score 0):

*I think you are going through little bit confusions.*

Although replacing:

```
echo $this->Form->input('users.users_id', array('default' => 1));
```

By:

```
echo $this->Form->input('users_id', array('default' => 1));
```

would simply fix your problem,You need to understand following things.

**[1. When to use association on saving ?](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#inserting-data)**

> If you are saving records on multiple table then only you need to use association, otherwise you don't need that in order to save records.

If you  need to save data on posts table only, simply do this:

```
$post = $this->Posts->patchEntity($post, $this->request->data]);
```

**[2. CakePHP Conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html)**

> Things would be easy when you follow CakePHP conventions.

If your table name is users,foreign key for another table would be user_id (instead of users_id).When you change this don't forget to change relations in respective models.

And replace this line in your form:

```
echo $this->Form->input('users.users_id', array('default' => 1));
```

By:

```
echo $this->Form->input('user_id', array('default' => 1)); 
// I consider user_id would be your field instead of users_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the suggestions, I agree with @Manohar Khadka that the database is a little messed up I will find out this. But the problem was here:

```
$post = $this->Posts->newEntity();
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $post = $this->Posts->patchEntity($post, $this->request->getData());
    $post->users_id = $post['users']['users_id'];
    if ($this->Posts->save($post)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('The post has been saved.'));

        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
    $this->Flash->error(__('The post could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
}
$users = $this->Posts->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
$this->set(compact('post', 'users'));
$this->set('_serialize', ['post']);
```

Specifically in this line:

```
$post->users_id = $post['users']['users_id'];
```

The value "users_id" was not received as it should, so it always came 0.

Comment: So have you read my answer carefully ? Why would you like to do this $post->users_id = $post['users']['users_id']; instead of simply changing input name to users_id from users.users_id ? There is no benefit for making things complex.I think It worth reading answer one more time.